# nginx php 110:connection timed out running nextcloud and wordpress

Tags: raspberry-pi, php, nginx, wordpress, nextcloud

I'm running a private server using *nginx* trying to host *wordpress* at the root of the directory and nextcloud in `/nextcloud`. Here is my *nginx* config file. There's probably lots of extra's I don't need in this because I've been trying to fix this error

```
"[error] 22206#22206: *109 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while sending request to upstream," ends up being a 504 Gateway Time-out.
```

The server itself is a *Raspberry Pi 3*, I have *mariadb* set up on a separate computer.

```
upstream php-handler {
#server 127.0.0.1:9000;
server unix: /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name xxxx;
# enforce https
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name xxxx;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/privkey.pem;

# Add headers to serve security related headers
# Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this
# topic first.
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
#add this begin
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
client_max_body_size 300m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_buffer_size 64k;
proxy_buffers   4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
#add this end
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;

# Path to the root of your installation
root /var/www/html/;
index index.php index.htm index.html;

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
# Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
# rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /nextcloud/public.php?service=host-meta
# last;
#rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json
# /nextcloud/public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

location = /.well-known/carddav {
  return 301 $scheme://$host/nextcloud/remote.php/dav;
}
location = /.well-known/caldav {
  return 301 $scheme://$host/nextcloud/remote.php/dav;
}

location /.well-known/acme-challenge { }

location ^~ /nextcloud {

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 512M;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

    # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
    # This module is currently not supported.
    #pagespeed off;

    location /nextcloud {
        rewrite ^ /nextcloud/index.php$uri;
    }

    location ~ ^/nextcloud/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^/nextcloud/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/nextcloud/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+)\.php(?:$|/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        #Avoid sending the security headers twice
        fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
        fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
        fastcgi_pass php-handler;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_request_buffering off;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    }

    location ~ ^/nextcloud/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
        try_files $uri/ =404;
        index index.php;
    }

    # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
    # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
    location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff|svg|gif)$ {
        try_files $uri /nextcloud/index.php$uri$is_args$args;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
        # Add headers to serve security related headers  (It is intended
        # to have those duplicated to the ones above)
        # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read
        # into this topic first.
        # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;
        # includeSubDomains; preload;";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
        add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        try_files $uri /nextcloud/index.php$uri$is_args$args;
        # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
        access_log off;
    }
}
location ~ \.php$ {
 try_files $uri =404;
 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
 include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 fastcgi_pass php-handler;
 fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
}
}
```

Also I haven't changed anything in the default `www.conf in pool.d`.

Comment: would you try clearing proxy header by adding following line in your configuration, `proxy_set_header Connection "";`

Comment: Added, and no change it seems.